# Auto incrementing 'id' value when inserting into sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to get id value into database in an auto increment way, i.e it sets it self automatically depending on what entry is.

here is how my DatabaseHandler code looks at the moments (only important bits)

```
    // Adding new appointment
    void addAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, appointment.getId()); // Appointment ID
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, appointment.getTitle()); // Appointment Title
        values.put(KEY_DETAILS, appointment.getDetails()); // Appointment Details
        values.put(KEY_DATE, appointment.getDate()); // Appointment Date
        values.put(KEY_TIME, appointment.getTime()); // Appointment Time

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_APPOINTMENTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

as you can see I use constructor without id in it, this always returns 0 for id, thus returns an error as id must be `PRIMARY KEY must be unique`

How do I make it auto increment?

Comment: Make it so: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`

Comment: @Vyger gives fatal syntax error

Comment: You have to comment out this line: `values.put(KEY_ID, appointment.getId()); // Appointment ID`

Comment: @Ilja I rolled back your edit since the table schema and error messages are very relevant for the question. If you want to pare it down, you can remove the `Appointment` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
values.put(KEY_ID, appointment.getId()); // Appointment ID
```

When the `PRIMARY KEY` is not specified, a value is [automatically generated](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: Will I need to change sql query to one provided in Vyger's answer?

Comment: @Ilja No. Adding the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword just changes the primary key generation slightly as explained in the linked sqlite documentation.

Comment: I also said in the comment the same you answered... So, why downvoting?

Comment: @Vyger The answer was missing the essential part and only contained irrelevant things. Happy to reverse my vote if an answer is edited to be helpful.

Comment: Now it makes no sense to reinsert my answer by adding my comment, once you already answered.