# Inserting to SQLite database in android and return an autoincremented value

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to work with android and SQLite database. Im not sure how to add data to this row of the table and get the gameid column which autoincrements returned back in the same method.
(this is my first post please excuse my posting errors)

```
public static final String GAME_COLUMNS = " ( GAME_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ADMIN_ID TEXT, SCORE1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0, SCORE2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 );";


public int createGame(String email){
    if(email!=null){
        SQLiteDatabase test = this.getWritableDatabase();
        test.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ GAME_TABLE + " VALUES(NULL, '"+ email + "',NULL, NULL);");
        int gameID = test.executeQuery("select last_insert_id() from "+GAME_TABLE);

        return gameID;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you checked with other posts on SO, may be this one can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441287/auto-incrementing-id-value-when-inserting-into-sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `select last_insert_id()`.

```
public int createGame(String email) {
    int result = -1;
    if (email!=null) {
        SQLiteDatabase test = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EMAIL, email);                                                                                                                                
        result = database.insert(GAME_TABLE, null, values); // this will return the last id you inserted
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The correct idea, but you had a broken return flow (this wouldn't  have compiled)